# SQL query on xml stored as nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nvarchar

[image: SQL Query on xml stored as nvarchar(max)]

I've been trying work through this query, but I cannot seem to find an answer specific to my question. There is a lot of information out there surrounding my question, but I cannot find a post that seems to answer it. I'm sure it is simple, but I just can't get it right. Here's what I have:

I have a column that stores XML data as `nvarchar(max)` and I trying to query the tags and not having much luck. Looking at the picture, `<VU>` is the root and I'm trying to get the value of `<CPort>` (80), but I cannot get the correct syntax. I have attached a screenshot for more clarity.

So far what I have is:

```
SELECT CAST(directory.dbo.unit.data AS XML) AS info
FROM Directory.dbo.unit
```

This lets me cast my column to XML, but I cannot query my newly cast column.

I tried:

```
SELECT CAST(directory.dbo.unit.data AS XML).query('(/VU/)') AS info
FROM Directory.dbo.unit
```

but this results as `NULL`. I also tried:

```
SELECT CAST(directory.dbo.unit.data AS XML).value('(/VU/CPort)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS info
FROM Directory.dbo.unit
```

This also results in `NULL`

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. Am I on the right track? Is casting the best way to query this. I tried sub-string, but that didn't work either. I do appreciate everyone's help with this. Let me know if you need more info or have more questions.

Comment: With your current select you may return more than one XML, so what will you use to select the correct XML value? Also, you may want to look at .nodes() as the way to select from your XML, so something like, SELECT a.value('CPort[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS info FROM xml.nodes('root/someOtherNode') AS x(a)

Comment: Posting data as an image isn't going to help here. Post some sample data as **text** so that we can actually test your SQL. Also, include the expected data for that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to say thanks everyone for your help and direction. I was able to finally get what I was looking for. I had to cast a couple of columns that contained xml data stored as nvarchar(max) and then tie in some additional columns, but I think this is going to work.
Here is my final solution below.

```
    With test as (Select Guid as guid, FirmwareVersion as FV, CAST(Directory.dbo.Unit.data as xml) as new, CAST(Directory.dbo.Unit.Location as xml) as loc from Directory.dbo.Unit)

        select UnitName1, Manufacturer, model, FV, IP, TimeZone, PhysicalName, [user], CameraName, LogicalID
        from (
            select distinct
            test.guid
            ,ue.name UnitName1
            ,test.new.value('(./VU/Mfct)[1]','varchar(100)') as Manufacturer
            ,test.new.value('(./VU/Model)[1]','varchar(100)') as Model
            ,test.new.value('(./VU/CAddr)[1]','varchar(100)') as IP
            ,test.loc.value('(./EntityLocation/TimeZoneId)[1]','varchar(100)') as TimeZone
            ,d.physicalname
            ,test.FV
            ,test.new.value('(./VU/User)[1]','varchar(100)') as [User]
            ,CE.NAME CameraName
            ,CE.LogicalID
            from test 
            inner join Directory.dbo.Device d on test.guid = d.unit
            INNER JOIN Directory.dbo.Entity UE ON test.Guid = uE.Guid
            INNER JOIN Directory.dbo.Stream S ON S.Device = D.GUID 
            INNER JOIN Directory.dbo.Camera C ON S.Camera = C.GUID 
            INNER JOIN Directory.dbo.Entity CE ON C.Guid = CE.Guid
            where charindex('Camera',d.PhysicalName,0) > 0
        ) x
        order by IP desc, guid, UnitName1, cameraname, LogicalID
```

It might not be the prettiest or most efficient way to write this, but it works for me! Thanks again everyone! techstudent01

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
declare @data table (text nvarchar(max) null);
insert @data values
('<VU><CPort>80</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>81</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>82</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>83</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>84</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>85</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>86</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>87</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>88</CPort></VU>'),
('<VU><CPort>89</CPort></VU>')
;

-- *** This is the important part ***
select cast(text as xml).value('(/VU/CPort)[1]', 'int') from @data;
```

Comment: @Ryan Wilson: I couldn't get nodes to work and I'm not sure why. I finally got my query to cast and I was able to use the value method to get my data.